# Get custom attribute from User class on Parse.com [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I'm working on a website with Parse.com and JavaScript. I have my "User" class, but I have added more fields than those that come by default.

I want to get one specific attribute from my User class (IdGroup) when user logs in, so I'm trying to capture the `IdGroup` using `user` object when login has been succesfully.

I have tried this:

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, pass, {
    success: function (user) {

        //var idGroup = user.get("IdGroup");

        localStorage.setItem("parseUser", true);
        localStorage.setItem("guestUser", false);
        localStorage.setItem("username", username);

        user.fetch().then(function (fetchedUser) {
            var idGroup = user.get("IdGroup");
            localStorage.setItem("IdGroup", idGroup);
        });

        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        alert('Invalid username or password!');
    }
});
```

This doesn't work.

If anyone could give me a hand, I will really appreciate.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's difficult to go on without any context. What does the script do? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have assumed that the user was already fetched at login.

But your callback function passes in the object fetchedUser, and you're accessing the user object. So, `var idGroup = fetchedUser.get("IdGroup");` is probably what you're looking for.